# Changing layout of a JPanel sent to JOptionPane with the pane still running

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Trying to change the look of a JOptionPane while its open, depending on which radiobutton the user clicks. What am I doing wrong? It works perfect if I for example add a button and move a JLabel from side to side of the window.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class ChangePanel extends JFrame{

private JButton click = new JButton("CLICK ME!");

ChangePanel(){
    add(click, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    click.addActionListener(new ButtonListen());

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public class ButtonListen implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        PopUpPanel pop = new PopUpPanel();
        showConfirmDialog(ChangePanel.this, pop, "Changeable", OK_CANCEL_OPTION);           
    }
}
//Send this as Parameter to the ConfirmDialog
public class PopUpPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JRadioButton jewelry = new JRadioButton("Jewelry");
    JRadioButton shares = new JRadioButton("Shares");
    JRadioButton machine = new JRadioButton("Machine");

    PopUpPanel(){

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        JPanel north = new JPanel();
        bg.add(jewelry);
        jewelry.addActionListener(this);
        bg.add(shares);
        shares.addActionListener(this);
        bg.add(machine);
        machine.addActionListener(this);
        north.add(jewelry);
        north.add(shares);
        north.add(machine);
        add(north); 
    }
    //Listener for RadioButtons
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JTextField info1Txt = new JTextField(12);
        JTextField info2Txt = new JTextField(12);
        JTextField info3Txt = new JTextField(3);;

        JRadioButton b = (JRadioButton)e.getSource();

        if(b.getText().equals("Jewelry")){
            //Dummy test text
            System.out.println("Jewelry");

            JPanel info1 = new JPanel();
            info1.add(new JLabel("info1:"));
            info1.add(info1Txt);
            add(info1);

            JPanel info2 = new JPanel();
            info2.add(new JLabel("info2:"));
            info2.add(info2Txt);
            add(info2);

            JPanel info3 = new JPanel();
            info3.add(new JLabel("info3:"));
            info3.add(info3Txt);
            add(info3);

            validate();
            repaint();

        }else if(b.getText().equals("Shares")){
            //Dummy test text
            System.out.println("Shares");
        }else
            //Dummy test text
            System.out.println("Machine");
    }   
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new ChangePanel();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with `BoxLayout`, you should provide size hints to the `PopUpPanel` panel, which you haven't given.

When a `BoxLayout` lays out components from top to bottom, it tries to size each component at the component's preferred height. If the vertical space of the layout does not match the sum of the preferred heights, then `BoxLayout` tries to resize the components to fill the space. The components either grow or shrink to fill the space, with `BoxLayout` honoring the minimum and maximum sizes of each of the components.

check out the official tutorial page discussion: [`BoxLayout` Feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#features)

Answer (score 0):

Call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after removing or adding components to it. So if you change the following lines:

```
validate();
repaint();
```

to:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

The content should appear. Though, it will not fit the original size of the `JOptionPane`. You can override `PopUpPanel.getPreferredSize()` to return desired size so that `JOptionPane` is packed properly, ie:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}
```

You can also use `JDialog` instead of `JOptionPane`.

Also, consider using `CardLayout` instead of swapping components manually. Check [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for examples.

Comment: It seems he is not swapping anything. He is just adding new component. `validate()` and `revalidate()` should not be issue, but it is good of you to suggest :)

Comment: @Sage I assumed that selecting different different combo box options will change the layout of the panel :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use **setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300))** in PopUpPanel constructor?  Works fine for me.  Good eye on revalidate and repaint.